# Padding getting disturbed on hover

Tags: html, css

So I wrote a where I add a `border-bottom` and `border-left` on `hover`.

The problem is that the elements move when I hover over an anchor element. What am I doing wrong here.

Here is the code : [nav menu with hover](http://codepen.io/dbajpeyi/pen/LqfCt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add such things to your css

```
.bmenu li a{
  border-bottom : 2px solid rgba(192,57,43,0); 
  border-left : 2px solid rgba(192,57,43,0);
}
```

or

```
.bmenu li a{
  border-bottom : 2px solid transparent; 
  border-left : 2px solid transparent;
}
```

as kind of placeholders before hovering is applied